# Closed form solution of a definite integral of an exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, approximation-theory

I've been trying to solve the following definite integral
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\, x^4\, \frac{e^{x^2+a}}{\left(e^{x^2+a}-1\right)^2}\quad , \qquad a>0\, .
$$
However, so far I could not find any solution. I'd prefer an exact one but a good approximation would be also nice.

I know that the following relations hold:
$$
\int_0^\infty x^d \frac{e^x}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^2} = d\Gamma(d)\zeta(d)\\
\int_0^\infty x^{d-1} \frac{1}{e^{x}-1} = \Gamma(d)\zeta(d)\\
\int_0^\infty x^{d-1} \text{ln}\{1-e^{-x}\} = -\Gamma(d)\zeta(d+1)\, .
$$
There are several ways I tried to solve this. Most of them are not worth mentioning. The most promising one is the following: I substituted $u\equiv x^2$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty du\, u^{\frac{3}{2}}\, \frac{e^{u+a}}{\left(e^{u+a}-1\right)^2}\, . 
$$
Then, one can see that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty du\, u^{\frac{3}{2}}\, \frac{e^{u+a}}{\left(e^{u+a}-1\right)^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^\infty du\, u^{\frac{3}{2}}\, \frac{1}{e^{u+a}-1}
$$
If one now substitutes $u^\prime\equiv u+a$ then the integration boundaries change from $1$ to $\infty$ such that one cannot use the above relations. For this reason, I considered an approximation for small $a$ around 0 by writing
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^\infty du\, u^{\frac{3}{2}}\, \frac{1}{e^{u}(1+a)-1}\, .
$$
Now, if one expands the integrand in $a$ up to infinite order, one gets
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^\infty du\, u^{\frac{3}{2}}\, \frac{1}{e^{u}-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-a\frac{e^u}{e^u-1}\right)^n\, .
$$
I know that the integral of the expression in the sum is a Hypergeometric function so maybe one could use partial integration. It did not take me anywhere at least.

Does anyone happen to know the result of this or how I could solve it. I am also happy with a nice approximation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting $t=e^{-a}$, substituting $x=y^{1/2}$ and using $z(1-z)^{-2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n$, you get [$\operatorname{Li}_{3/2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm): $$\ldots=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{3/2}te^{-y}}{(1-te^{-y})^2}\,dy=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty nt^n\int_0^\infty y^{3/2}e^{-ny}\,dy=\frac{3\sqrt\pi}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: Nice solution ! The problem is so simple ... after reading it ! Cheers and $\to +1$.

Comment: Short and easy to follow answer :) ! A follow up question: The original exponent was $\sqrt{x^4+2 x^2}$. I was not able to solve it so I approximated it for large x to $x+a$. Can you think of a result for the exact one?

Comment: @mr.curious: Not really. Substitution $x^4+2x^2=\sinh^2 y$ gives (in the end) a crazy series composed of Bessel functions. Another idea might be to use $y=\sqrt{x^4+2x^2}$ as $x=(\sqrt{1+iy}-\sqrt{1-iy})/(i\sqrt{2})$ somehow.

Comment: @metamorphy , you gave some really good hints. Unfortunately, I couldn't get very far. I was thinking of writing $\sqrt{x^4 + 2 x^2} \approx \sqrt{2} x + a x^3$ as a good approximation, but couldn't think of any useful substitution. How about you, do you see how one can solve this modified problem?